# Building and uploading images to Docker Hub, how to from Docker Compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-registry, dockerhub

I have been working in a `docker` environment for PHP development and finally I get it working as I need. This environment relies on `docker-compose` and the config looks like:

```
version: '2'
services:
    php-apache:
        env_file:
          - dev_variables.env
        image: reynierpm/php55-dev
        build:
            context: .
            args:
                - PUID=1000
                - PGID=1000
        ports:
            - "80:80"
        extra_hosts:
            - "dockerhost:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"
        volumes:
            - ~/var/www:/var/www
```

There are some configurations like `extra_hosts` and `env-file` that is giving me some headache. Why? Because I don't know if the image will works under such circumstances.

Let's said:

- I have run `docker-compose up -d` and the image `reynierpm/php55-dev` with tag `latest` has been built
- I have everything working as it should be because I am setting the proper values on the `docker-compose.yml` file
- I have logged in into my account and I push the image to the repository: `docker push reynierpm/php55-dev`

What happen if tomorrow you clone the repository and try to run `docker-compose up` but changing the `docker-compose.yml` file to fit your settings? How the image behaves in this case? I mean makes sense to create/upload the image to Docker Hub if any time I run the command `docker-compose up` it will be build again due to the changes on the config file?

Maybe I am completing wrong and some magic happen behind scenes but I need to know if I am doing this right

Comment: Hello, did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If people clone your git repository and do a `docker-compose up -d` it will in fact building a new image. If you only want people use your image from docker hub, drop the build section of docker-compose.yml and publish it in your docker hub page. Check [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/crramirez/limesurvey/) you can see the proposed docker-compose.yml.

Just paste this in your page:

```yaml
version: '2'
services:
  php-apache:
    image: reynierpm/php55-dev
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    environment:
      DOCKERHOST: 'yourhostip'
      PHP_ERROR_REPORTING: 'E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_NOTICE'
    volumes:
      - ~/var/www:/var/www
```

If your env_file just have a couple of variables it is better to show them  directly in the Dockerfile. It is better to replace extra_hosts with an environment variable and change in your php.ini or where ever you use the extra host by the variable:

```
.....
xdebug.remote_host         = ${DOCKERHOST}
.....
```

You can in your Dockerfile define a default value for this variable:

```
ENV DOCKERHOST=localhost
```

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: I believe that use my built image wont work since that image will have the parameters setup for my local PC and wont work for others. I am right?

Comment: It just depends on your Dockerfile and how you are using your environment variables. In fact in rare cases the env variables values are used to build the image. I can't find your github repo in docker hub. You can post here to have a look

Comment: [Here is the repo in DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/reynierpm/php55-dev/) and [here is in Github](https://github.com/reypm/php55-dev) let me know your thoughs on this

Comment: In fact the environment variables are used in entrypoint so they won't get into the image. The args PUID and PGID are part of the build process. Why you need to specify those values to create the docker user? For host mounted volumes? Think there should be a workaround

Comment: I am not using them for anything right now. What do you mean with should be a workaround?

Comment: If you are not using them leave them with the default values in the Dockerfile and don't say anything in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: I haven't the time to test all this but thanks, your answer has been accepted

Comment: Well tell us how was going when you test and solve the issue.

Comment: I have managed to build the image successfully but now I have a few doubts, you said: *Try to specify the environment variables instead an env_file and describe each one. If the env variables affect how you build the image, move those scripts to an entrypoint script, so it will be run each time the container starts and allow changing things without building a new image.* can you improve your answer by adding an example on how to add them to the entrypoint based on my repository?